# UWP VSIX project templates gives exception

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm developing VSIX project templates for UWP with custom wizard. I exported the Microsoft's Blank app project as template and included it in my VSIX project. It will call the WizardImplementation class as expected. After run started, and ShouldAddProjectItem executed, it gives exception as "general exception". Dont know why. Please help.

**Update:**

I have 2 templates (dummy template for get user inputs and main template) and 2 wizards (root wizard with UI and main wizard). Below is my process.

1. Calling root wizard from the dummy template.
2. Then I add the main template from the root wizard using Solution2.AddFromTemplate().
3. Then calling main wizard from the main template.

After the above process, after the execution of the ShouldAddProjectItem() of the main wizard, the exception thrown in Solution2.AddFromTemplate().

Please find my sample simple demo in this repo https://github.com/mathikp/MySampleProjectTemplate

[image: Exception]

[image: Exception detail]

Comment: Please share a simple demo which could reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ColeWu-MSFT I have updated my question with more details. Please find my sample simple demo in this repo https://github.com/mathikp/MySampleProjectTemplate

Comment: I have download the project and reproduce the issue on my side, as a workaround, if you want to add multiple projects to your project, please refer to:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308.aspx

Comment: This is not suitable for my requirement. I need to decide the second project's name and location in the run time and add it to the solution dynamically. And also I'm using the same process for some of my other template sources, which are working fine. I dont know what is the problem with this.:(